# How to update a JavaFX GUI correctly while processing data

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get into JavaFX for making first attempts in making GUIs with Java. Therefore I made a simple neural network which learns the XOR and displays the output in JavaFX. My question is - how can I update the GUI regularly while processing the data?

Everything I achieved so far is a single update in the GUI when the network finished learning. Even if I started the networking in a thread.

I expect that the right handed side of the GUI updates (circle change the colors in dependence of the output) regularly for each n epoch and not only once. The attached image shows the GUI before the network started. [image: XOR Neural Network before Start]

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX has an "Event Thread", which is responsible for handling button clicks, updating labels, and any other GUI-related tasks. When you call `button.setOnAction(e -> doSomething());`, when your button is pressed, `doSomething()` happens on the JavaFX thread. During the time that this is running, no other GUI events can occur. This means your interface will completely freeze, which leads to a bad user experience.

Also, you cannot perform GUI operations on any thread other than the JavaFX thread, or you will get an `IllegalStateException`. (Try calling `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> label.setText("hello"));` to see this in action)

Luckily, JavaFX provides methods to get around this.

First, and easiest, is to call your long-running method inside a new thread (perhaps with `ExecutorService`s as above), and when you need to modify the interface, wrap those calls in a call to `Platform.runLater(() -> updateInterface());`. This will post `updateInterface()` to the GUI thread, and will allow it to run.

However, this can be messy, so the preferred method is to use a `Service`.

Assume your long running calculation returns an `Double`, you create a class extending `Service<Double>`, override its `createTask()` method, and perform the calculation there, as such:

```
public class CalculationService extends Service<Double> {
    @Override
    protected Task<Double> createTask() {
        return new Task<Double>() {
            @Override
            protected Double call() throws Exception {
                return doCalculation();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then, in your controller, declare a `private final CalculationService service = new CalculationService();`

In your controller's `initialize()` method, you can then bind the output of this service to anything you want. For example:

```
calculationDisplayLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(service.valueProperty()));
// continuously updates the label whenever the service calculates a new value
```

Then, whenever you decide you want to start calculating again, you call `service.restart()` to interrupt the process if it is running, and start again from the beginning.

If you want to call code when the value changes, add a listener to the value of the service. For example, if you want it to recalculate as soon as it has finished, call:

```
service.valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, newValue) -> service.restart());
```

If in doubt, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html

Comment: First of all - thanks for your help! I just have two more questions. 1. When I'm using the Platform.runLater or the Service approach - do I still need the ObservableList to inform the GUI or can I get rid of that List? 2. You wrote "Assume your long running calculation returns an Double [...]" - the calculation returns a double array for each 500 iterations, I understand your answer as that I'm only able to retrieve a single return once the service started. How can I get intermediate results (each 500 iterations) with this approach?

Comment: 1) You will still need an `ObservableList` to back any `ListView` you have in your interface. I usually create a `private final ObservableList<Data> items = ...` and then `listVIew.setItems(items);`. Then, if I want to update the list, I call `items.setAll(newList);`

Comment: 2) You can include state in your `Service` class, you could move the network there, and make your service return `SomeCustomDataObject` that contains not only the value, but the number of iterations that have happened so far. Then, when the service is called, it modifies the network, updates the weights, then returns its value in a JavaFX-friendly way. This would make it so that each subsequent call to `service.restart()` gets the next value in the sequence.